# Howto deploy sinatra application that uses postgresql to appfog

Tags: postgresql, deployment, sinatra, appfog

I'm trying to deploy a simple sinatra application to appfog, the database backend is postgresql.

Here's what I've come up with

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'

if ENV['VCAP_SERVICES']
  require 'json'
  services = JSON.parse(ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'])
  postgresql_key = services.keys.select { |svc| svc =~ /postgresql/i }.first
  postgresql = services[postgresql_key].first['credentials']
  postgresql_conn = "postgres://"+postgresql['user']+":"+postgresql['password']+ \
    "@"+postgresql['host']+":"+postgresql['port']+"/"+postgresql['name']
  DataMapper.setup(:default, postgresql_conn)
else
  DataMapper.setup(:default, "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/todo_list")
end
```

My manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
  .:
    name: supertasks
    framework:
      name: sinatra
      info:
        mem: 128M
        description: Sinatra Application
        exec: ruby web.rb
    infra: hp
    url: ${name}.${target-base}
    mem: 128M
    instances: 1
    services:
      postgresql-4aaf:
        type: postgresql
```

And my Gemfile has the following code

```
source :rubygems

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem "pg"
gem 'data_mapper'
gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
gem 'json'
```

I get the following error when I try to start the application

```
    Error: Application [supertasks] failed to start, logs information below.                                                                               

====> /logs/staging.log <====

# Logfile created on 2012-10-08 18:59:58 +0000 by logger.rb/25413
Adding json-1.7.5.gem to app...
Adding data_mapper-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding dm-core-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding addressable-2.2.8.gem to app...
Adding dm-aggregates-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding dm-constraints-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding dm-migrations-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding dm-serializer-1.2.2.gem to app...
Adding fastercsv-1.5.5.gem to app...
Adding json_pure-1.7.5.gem to app...
Adding multi_json-1.3.6.gem to app...
Adding dm-timestamps-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding dm-transactions-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding dm-types-1.2.2.gem to app...
Adding bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1.gem to app...
Adding stringex-1.4.0.gem to app...
Adding uuidtools-2.1.3.gem to app...
Adding dm-validations-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding dm-postgres-adapter-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding dm-do-adapter-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding data_objects-0.10.9.gem to app...
Adding do_postgres-0.10.9.gem to app...
Adding pg-0.14.1.gem to app...
Adding sinatra-1.3.3.gem to app...
Adding rack-1.4.1.gem to app...
Adding rack-protection-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding tilt-1.3.3.gem to app...
Adding thin-1.5.0.gem to app...
Adding daemons-1.1.9.gem to app...
Adding eventmachine-1.0.0.gem to app...
Adding bundler-1.1.3.gem to app...
Adding cf-autoconfig-0.0.4.gem to app...
Adding cf-runtime-0.0.2.gem to app. server error occurr...
```

Does anyone know how to set up a sinatra app that uses a postgresql database with appfog?

Answer (score 3):

I tried running your code on af myself and it looks to be correct.  Have you bound the DB to your app yet?  To bind "services" to apps in appfog you have to go through these steps in the af cli:

```
af bind-service <servicename> <appname>
```

You can also bind the DB in the appfog console at console.appfog.com under the services tab of your app.